# Variable not assigning correctly inside a for loop

Tags: python, loops, variables

I feel like this is a very obvious fix that I'm missing and a small snippet taken from my main programme.

```
emptyBoard = [['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
for i in range(3):
    otherBoard = emptyBoard
    otherBoard[1][i] = 'Y'
    print(otherBoard)
```

When run the programme outputs the following :

```
[['N', 'N', 'N'], ['Y', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
[['N', 'N', 'N'], ['Y', 'Y', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
[['N', 'N', 'N'], ['Y', 'Y', 'Y'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
```

But my desired output would be:

```
[['N', 'N', 'N'], ['Y', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
[['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'Y', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
[['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'Y'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
```

My intention is to reset otherBoard to emptyBoard with every new iteration , but that doesn't seem to be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`otherBoard = emptyBoard` makes both variables point at the same list. Since both variables are pointing at the same object, changing that object will reflect through both variables.

The easiest way to do what you actually want should be this:

```
import copy

emptyBoard = [['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
for i in range(3):
    otherBoard = copy.deepcopy(emptyBoard)  
    otherBoard[1][i] = 'Y'
    print(otherBoard)
```

`copy.deepcopy()` will create a different but identical copy of the given list and its sublists. Then, you assign `otherBoard` to point to that new, completely separate, copied list, and any changes you make will not reflect on the old list.

---

A quicker but possibly more error-prone solution, which doesn't require any extra imports, would be

```
emptyBoard = [['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
for i in range(3):
    otherBoard = emptyBoard
    oldValue = otherBoard[1][i]
    otherBoard[1][i] = 'Y'
    print(otherBoard)
    otherBoard[1][i] = oldValue
```

simply changing the list and then changing it back immediately afterwards.

Comment: Thanks very much , would you be able to help me understand why oldValue doesn't also change to 'Y' on line 5. Because surely assigning oldValue to otherBoard[1][i] would mean  oldValue would also be changed on line 5. Or have I misunderstood the article linked above?

Comment: Or, rather than copying an existing empty board, define a function that *creates* a new empty board to be modified.

Comment: @FreddieMoore The name `oldValue` points at the same value that `otherBoard[1][i]` pointed at. Then, `otherBoard[1][i]` is made to point to something else, but that doesn't change what `oldValue` was pointing at. For me it's easiest to think about variables in python as "every variable name is a pointer to the actual value", and thus "assigning" a new value to a name is actually pointing that name at a different value. Other names that were pointing to the same value are unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to do the task.
Actually, `otherBoard = emptyBoard` doesn't make a second list.
Both the `otherBoard` and `emptyBoard` refer to the same list after the assignment because the assignment just replicates the reference to the list.

```
emptyBoard = [['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N']]
for i in range(3):
    otherBoard = emptyBoard.copy()
    secondbord = otherBoard[1].copy()
    secondbord[i] = 'Y'
    otherBoard[1] = secondbord
    print(otherBoard)
```